# VLOOKUP frustration

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to use Vlookup in Excel and can't seem to get it right.  I am not an expert at all with Excel.  Here is the scenario

I am searching info trying to confirm my State/City (StCity) matches to a mileage table

My formula is `"=VLOOKUP([@[STPLUSCITY_ORIG]],MileageDist,1,TRUE)"`

```
Col 1 (StCity Orig)     Col2(result of formula)

TXCarrollton              AZYuma
NCMorrisville             AZYuma
NCMorrisville             AZYuma
NCMorrisville             AZYuma
NCMorrisville             AZYuma
NCMorrisville             AZYuma
TXSocorro                 AZYuma
TXSocorro                 AZYuma
TXSocorro                 AZYuma
TXSocorro                 AZYuma
```

Table Array Data

```
  Col 1 (StCity)

   CABakersfield
   MABoston
   TXCarrollton
   ILChicago
   FLOrlando
   AZYuma
```

As you can see, my result always returns AzYuma regardless of what city is referenced.  I have modified the "true/false" as well changed the font, modified the upper case/lower case, etc.  I just can't figure out how to get the results I am looking for.

Comment: Change `True` to `False` in your formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `True` to `False` in your formula the frustration would be gone.

In general, consider `Index(Match())`, instead of `Vlookup`. [index match vs vlookup](https://www.google.com/search?q=index%20match%20vs%20vlookup&oq=index%20match%20vs%20&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3471j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[Here is a bit more concerning Vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1):

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: I did change the "true" to "false", I received the "#N/A" results

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX() + MATCH()` are great for retrieving data horizontally but if you just want to confirm the existence use `COUNTIF()`.

Comment: Thank you for your response!